# Re Issue a connection with Libcurl after a timeout

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I have made a long polling client with Libcurl C++

Set the timeout at 30 secconds via:

```
curl_easy_setopt(longPollingHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30L);
```

How do I re issue the HTTP get request after the operation has timed out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is interested.

I just checked the status of the CURLcode. If it is != 0 re issue the request.

```
if(res != 0)
    {
        cout << "Timeout : Repolling " << endl;
        continue;
    }
```

Where continue returns to the beginning of the loop where i issue a curl_easy_perform again.

Thanks

Comment: Worth pointing out to anyone coming here that 0 is defined as CURLE_OK in libcurl, better to use the curl specific constants for return codes